# templated generic setter for unique_ptr<T> member

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to create a generic setter, supporting values and pointers.
I'm having trouble with pointers. Minimal code that illustrates the main idea:

```
#include <memory>
#include <variant>

class A{
    int s;
};

template <typename uniq, typename ptr>
void set(uniq &u, const ptr &p){
    u = std::unique_ptr<decltype(*std::declval<ptr>)>(p);
}

int main(){
    std::variant<std::unique_ptr<A>> dd;
    set(dd, new A);
}
```

Compilation (gcc-7.3.0) fails with

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<A*&& (&)() noexcept, std::default_delete<A*&& (&)() noexcept> >::unique_ptr(A* const&)’
```

I'm out of ideas about how to get the pointer type...
Also, where does the reference come from? (changing the ptr parameter doesn't solve it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct `std::unique_ptr` explicitly:

```
template <typename uniq, typename ptr>
void set(uniq &u, const ptr &p)
{
    using T = std::remove_pointer_t<ptr>;
    u = std::unique_ptr<T>(p);
}
```

Comment: edited question to show why reconstruction is necessary

Answer (score 6):

You just have a typo here:

```
template <typename uniq, typename ptr>
void set(uniq &u, const ptr &p){
    u = std::unique_ptr<decltype(*std::declval<ptr>)>(p);
    //                                            ^^^
}
```

`std::declval` is a function, so the code you're writing is trying to dereference that function type. Which is a valid thing to do! That's how you get `A*&& (&)() noexcept`

What you want is:

```
template <typename uniq, typename ptr>
void set(uniq &u, const ptr &p){
    u = std::unique_ptr<decltype(*std::declval<ptr>())>(p);
}
```

Which you can write a lot simpler by just directly using the name `p`:

```
template <typename uniq, typename ptr>
void set(uniq &u, const ptr &p){
    u = std::unique_ptr<decltype(*p)>(p);
}
```

But this probably isn't actually correct since `decltype(*p)` would typically have a reference type, and you have to remove it:

```
template <typename uniq, typename ptr>
void set(uniq &u, const ptr &p){
    u = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*p)>>(p);
}
```

Now, this code *really* only works with a raw pointer (you'd have to `move` a `unique_ptr` and you can't convert a `shared_ptr` to a `unique_ptr`), so you could more clearly express that in the function signature which also makes the body much easier to write:

```
template <typename uniq, typename T>
void set(uniq &u, T* p){
    u = std::unique_ptr<T>(p);
}
```

---

Which ultimately begs the question of why you would want to write:

```
set(dd, new A);
```

instead of:

```
dd = std::make_unique<A>();
```

anyway? The 2nd is far superior.

Comment: wouldn't be **okay** to use just `std::decay_t` instead `std::remove_reference_t`? Just a doubt.

Comment: @JeJo No, you _only_ want to remove the reference, not the `const`. If you had an `int const*`, that would dereference to `int const&` and you want `int const` back, not `int`.

Comment: Why I write it like this is because it is part of my poor man's reflection implementation. And I need to set types I know nothing about.

Comment: @serafean it's impossible to implement reflection with templates. when using templates, the compiler needs to know all the types in compile time, which is the opposite of reflection - inspecting types in runtime. (not to mention that implementing reflection is not an easy task even for a big team of experienced C++ developers).

Comment: Right, reflection is too big a word. Serializability and unserializability would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Barry thanks for the thorough explanation of my typo.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation is a bit odd. if you know you're going to set a `unique_ptr` on `u`, then why templatize is as `uniq` and not as `std::unique_ptr<type>` ?

Considering what I wrote above, I would implement it as

```
template <class type>
void set(std::unique_ptr<type>& unique_pointer, type* pointer) {
    unique_pointer.reset(pointer);
}

template <class type, class ... argument_types>
void set(std::unique_ptr<type>& unique_pointer, argument_types&& ... args) {
    unique_pointer = std::make_unique<type>(std::forward<argument_types>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> up0, up1, up2, up3;

    set(up0);
    set(up1, "hello world");
    set(up2, "   hello world   ", 3, 11);
    set(up3, new std::string("hello world"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::unique_ptr<>::reset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset):

```
std::variant<std::unique_ptr<A>> u;
A* p = new A;
std::get<0>(u).reset(p);
```

Or:

```
using unique_ptr_type = typename std::decay<decltype(std::get<0>(u))>::type;
u = unique_ptr_type(p);
```

Comment: edited to show why I'm forcing the constructor call.

Comment: @serafean Updated the answer for you.